# How to implement a 3-tier architecture in MVC5 WCF

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-5, 3-tier

Forgive me if this question has been asked already, I really did not want to ask this if it had already been addressed but I have not been successful in finding it.

Needless to say, I have an existing web application in ASP.NET MVC 5.  The client I built it for needs the application to be in a 3-tier architecture so that the View, Business Logic and Model are deployed on separate servers for security reasons.  I have never developed a three-tier architecture and have been led to believe that the use of WCF (windows communication foundation) would aid in this implementation.

As I am not used to using WCF or familiar with the actual implementation of a 3-tier architecture I have come seeking help on how I would go about converting my existing application to meet this requirement.  I do understand the concept of how a three-tier architecture works, so there is no need to elaborate on the topic itself.  My concern lies more with best practices for implementing it using my existing entity framework and LINQ queries as well as how to implement WCF for API interactions with the separate tiers.

I have found 1 tutorial for MVC 3, but it does not make use of WCF and does not discuss deployment of the application or even seem compatible with MVC 5.

Any links to a good tutorial or book on how to implement this architecture using MVC 5 and WCF would be welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try These Links :
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/d13d20/creating-aspnet-mvc-app-with-wcf-service-docx/
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/788580/WCF-RESTful-service-and-WebGrid-in-ASP-NET-MVC-P

Comment: These links look promising.  Thank you.

Comment: The C# corner link above was very helpful.  Despite having to tweak it a bit to get it to work for MVC-5, since it is a MVC-4 tutorial,  it worked well and got me started.  Thanks again for the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am posting this as an answer, only since there has been no more activity since I posed the initial question.  Please use [@Khurram Ali's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1776785/khurram-ali) links above if you are looking for an answer to this issue.

I will sum it up quickly here by saying that the architecture can be achieved by implementing a WCF service:

In Visual Studio 2013, select **"FILE"** from the toolbar, then hover over **"New"** then select **"Website**".  Depending on what language you want to use select either Visual Basic or Visual C# from the **"Templates"** on the left and in the main list select WCF Service.  Then select the path you wish to save your service.  By default the service is named WCFService1, so you may change this if you wish.  Once you have created your service, its role in the three tier architecture is to make queries to the database, and to serve the results of those queries to the presentation layer, so that the presentation layer does not make the queries directly to the database itself.  Business Logic AKA; SQL stored procedures can be added to this service as well.

To reiterate, from my initial question, I have never used WCF for any projects so I did not know how to get started on this.  The links that [@Khurram Ali](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1776785/khurram-ali) provided were very helpful.